# Why does `new Array(...[ 7 ])` produce `Array(7) [ <7 empty slots> ]`?

Tags: javascript, arrays, spread-syntax

Why does this code print `Array(7) [ <7 empty slots> ]` (or an array of `undefined`, 7 times) instead of an array with the single element `7`?

```js
const a = [ 7 ];

console.log(new Array(...a));
```

Comment: Make sure to read [how `Array` can be invoked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Array). The array constructor is... not terribly well thought out. If you want a new array from elements, using [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) is much safer, as it does not have the 1-element exception.

Comment: Consider using [`Array.of()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/of) for your expected result

Comment: Related: [What is the use case for Javascript's (ES6) Array.of()?](/q/31686360/4642212).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

new Array(...a) is the same as saying new Array(7), which will create an empty array with 7 undefined spots.

Comment: i just found that there are two options of creating Arrays
`new Array(element0, element1, /* … ,*/ elementN)` and
`new Array(arrayLength)
` 
so in my code works second option

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use spread in an array do it like this

```
console.log([...a])
```

Comment: Or just use `a.slice()`.